# Fancybox link doesn't work (Lightbox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a lightbox (using fancybox.net) here: http://desertcinema.com/home-test/

[image]

And I use a gallery codes to show images in gallery form:

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".gallery").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
```

And here's my HTML:

```
  <li class="portfolio-box photography">
            <a class="gallery" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/SKRE-9-30sp4bav1hxsgwj54nvaww.jpg" title="Concealment">
                <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/SKRE-9-30sp4baun93pvbri4pf1ts.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="mask"></div>
                <div class="line-folio"></div>
                <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                <h4>Concealment</h4>
            </a>
        </li>


    <li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
            <a class="gallery" rel=gallery1" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/Mike-Full-Draw-30sp495yqivl82ubkxq5mo.jpg" title="Concealment">
                <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/SKRE-9-30sp4baun93pvbri4pf1ts.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="mask"></div>
                <div class="line-folio"></div>
                <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                <h4>Concealment</h4>
            </a>
        </li>
```

using the class "gallery" that I place on `<a href="">` however when clicking this images there is no next or previous button which must be working.

I just followed this instruction: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples

am I making any mistakes? You can inspect element using Chrome if you want.

Comment: can you please make fiddle for this?

Comment: I am working on a custom php file. You can inspect element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.You are missing rel="gallery1" in first < a >

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
<link href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<li class="portfolio-box photography">
            <a class="gallery"  rel="gallery1" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/SKRE-9-30sp4bav1hxsgwj54nvaww.jpg" title="Concealment">
                <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/SKRE-9-30sp4baun93pvbri4pf1ts.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="mask"></div>
                <div class="line-folio"></div>
                <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                <h4>Concealment</h4>
            </a>
        </li>


    <li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
            <a class="gallery"  rel="gallery1" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/Mike-Full-Draw-30sp495yqivl82ubkxq5mo.jpg" title="Concealment">
                <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/SKRE-9-30sp4baun93pvbri4pf1ts.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="mask"></div>
                <div class="line-folio"></div>
                <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                <h4>Concealment</h4>
            </a>
        </li>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".gallery").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

try this way.. No div should be there in li

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
  openEffect : 'none',
  closeEffect : 'none'
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>

<script src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
<link href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


            <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1617/24108587812_6c9825d0da_b.jpg" title="Morning Godafoss (Brads5)">
 <img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1617/24108587812_6c9825d0da_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3691/10185053775_701272da37_b.jpg" title="Vertical - Special Edition! (cedarsphoto)">
 <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3691/10185053775_701272da37_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/574/22407305427_69cc6e845f_b.jpg" title="Racing against the Protons (tom.leuzi)">
 <img src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/574/22407305427_69cc6e845f_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/291/18653638823_a86b58523c_b.jpg" title="Lupines (Kiddi Einars)">
 <img src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/291/18653638823_a86b58523c_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

Comment: Sorry those are required markup for the website. Can't remove those div and elements.